# Intercept/Callback for QuickFIX message

Tags: callback, quickfix, intercept

I am using a FIX protocol to communicate with one of our counterparties. I have used Camel with Spring to build my communication routes.

I have a requirement where in my counterparty is expecting an ACK for every request it sends to me.
For example:

1. TradeCaptureRequestAck in response to TradeCaptureRequest
2. AllocationReportAck in response to AllocationReport
3. Confirmation_Ack in response to Confirmation

They are expecting a response irrespective of what happens at our end (even if something fails or exception occurs).

***One way*** I know we can intercept the incoming message via MessageFactory. We can create a custom messagefactory and inject it in while creating **QuickFixJComponent** bean.
***Problem with this approach*** is at factory level I will just be able to get the message type like TradeCaptureReport, AllocationReport etc. but not the content because factory only creates (and returns) the appropriate Message object. Actual work of populating this message object with incoming message data happens in Session class I guess (not sure about this).

Can someone please tell me if there is a way I can get or intercept the request message as soon as it reaches the route so that I can send the appropriate ACK to counterparty?

Comment: Are you really using QuickFIX?  Because it sounds like you're avoiding the completely sensible QuickFIX way of doing things.

Comment: @Grant Birchmeier Of Course I am using QuickFIX. Apache Camel QuickFIXJ component to be precise. I have found something which partially fulfils my need i.e. interceptors. It will send the ACK as soon as incoming message hits from(URI). But I am still searching for a way to send the ACK even if something fails during validation.